# Migrating from maven-ant-tasks to aether-ant-tasks

Tags: ant, maven-ant-tasks, aether-ant

As part of packaging software for the Fedora project, I'd like to update an upstream ant build that uses maven-ant-tasks for dependency resolution to use aether-ant-tasks.  These two libraries are frustratingly close to one another, but they're not totally compatible.  In particular, this build uses multiple `<dependencies>` elements to declare multiple classpaths and filesets; this is OK for maven-ant-tasks but not (as far as I can tell) OK for aether-ant-tasks.  Is there a good way to handle this use case in aether-ant-tasks?

Comment: Asking for a guide is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you can post your current Ant build, and the specific issue you have with using `aether-ant-tasks`. Btw, did you go through https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Ant_Tasks?

Comment: Thanks, @Tunaki.  I've kept my specific issue in the question but removed the general request for a guide.  (The docs don't address this question.)